# Get sequential dates in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to query a Postgres database to retrieve records for a specific customer that are from dates that are adjacent to the current day.

So for example:

- If today is Wednesday, it will pull the records from Monday and Tuesday if they exist.
- If today is Wednesday, it will not pull a record from Monday if Tuesday does not have a record.
- If pulling a record from last Wednesday, it will pull Tuesday and Thursday if they exist.

The database is currently structured with a Dates table that contains:

```
 Id----------|------DateTime--------
```

And the Id has a foreign key relationship with the Customers table containing:

```
CustomerId-------|-----DateId(fk)-----|----other columns.....
```

I have thought to simply query the database if the date exists before and after the queried date (and pull that record if exists), and then loop such that a success will query the next date before or after..... but that seems horribly inefficient.

Is there a better method to obtain these records?

EDIT: 
Example Dates table:

```
Id    | DateTime
1     | '2018-01-23 16:19:17.600305'
2     | '2018-01-24 00:03:11.213492'
3     | '2018-01-25 03:10:14.911771'
```

Sample Customers table:

```
Id  |   DateId   |   CustomerId   |    Location1   |   Location2   |   Transport   
66  |     2      |       2        |     Market     |    Library    |   Car
67  |     2      |       3        |     Bookstore  |    Library    |   Car
68  |     3      |       3        |     Pool       |    Town       |   Car
69  |     3      |       3        |     Pool       |    Town       |   Bus
```

Comment: Sample data would really help.  Can a customer have more than one record on a given day?  Is there a time component?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: So, in your question, "current day" is a parameter to the query, or is it today?  While I am not sure I understand the entire question, it seems like this could be expressed as a complex WHERE clause, with several disjunctive clauses covering the different scenarios.  It's not pretty, but would not that work?

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and use the `lag` and `lead` window functions with a window clause like `OVER (ORDER BY dates.datetime)`.